# Split a string and remove the first element in string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, split

```
 Original string                  '4.0.0-4.0-M-672092'
```

How to modify the Original string to "4.0-M-672092" using a one line code.
Any Help is highly appreciated .

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please explain the rule you want to follow here.   Do you just want to remove the first 5 characters in every case, you can do that by saying mystring[0..4]=''?  Or remove everything up to the first '-'?  mystring.split('-').shift.join('-')?  Or is there some other logic/requirement here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'split' method works in this case

> https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split

```ruby
'4.0.0-4.0-M-672092'.split('-')[1..-1].join('-')

# => "4.0-M-672092"
```

Just be careful, in this application is fine, but in long texts this might become unoptimized, since it splits all the string and then joins the array all over again

---

If you need this in wider texts to be more optimized, you can find the "-" index (which is your split) and use the next position to make a substring

```ruby
text = '4.0.0-4.0-M-672092'
text[(text.index('-') + 1)..-1]

# => "4.0-M-672092"
```

But you can't do it in one line, and not finding a split character will result in an error, so use a rescue statement if that is possible to happen

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

`'4.0.0-4.0-M-672092'.split('-', 2).second`

Answer (score 0):

```
"4.0.0-4.0-M-672092"[/(?<=-).*/]
  #=> "4.0-M-672092"
```

The regular expression reads, "Match zero or more characters other than newlines, as many as possible (`.*`), provided the match is preceded by a hyphen. `(?<=-)` is a *positive lookbehind*. See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).